# word.open() error - Attempted to read or write protected memory

Tags: c#, memory, file-io, ms-word, protected

I am trying to open the word document as follows.

```
 wordDocument = wordApplication.Documents.Open(ref paramSourceDocPath, 
   ref paramMissing, ref paramMissing, ref paramMissing, ref paramMissing, 
   ref paramMissing, ref paramMissing, ref paramMissing, ref paramMissing, 
   ref paramMissing, ref paramMissing, ref paramMissing, ref paramMissing, 
   ref paramMissing, ref paramMissing, ref paramMissing);
```

And i am receiving the error Attempted to read or write protected memory.

Comment: This is the sort of thing that can happen if you access Word or other Office products through the Automation interfaces, from a multi-threaded or server application.

Answer (score -1):

I'm pretty sure that all those paramMissing reference arguments are your problem.